# how to convert file input to base64 - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a file input and I want to convert it to base64 and send to server side. this is my code:

```
var avatar = (this.refs.avatar) ? this.refs.avatar.files : "" ;

if(avatar.length > 0){
  avatar = avatar[0]
  let fileReader = new FileReader();
  let file = null;
  fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
       file = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;

   };
   fileReader.readAsDataURL(avatar);
}else{
  avatar = ""
}

console.log(avatar); //File(2468670) {name: "wood.png", lastModified: 1524227213060, lastModifiedDate: Fri Apr 20 2018 16:56:53 GMT+0430 (+0430), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 2468670, …}
```

should I covert `avatar` to base64? 
I should convert to origin file on server side.

Comment: Why do you  need to convert it? Uploading it will convert it to the proper MIME Type. The server can handle it from there.

Comment: My web-service require a base64 string parameter.

Comment: your code does the job, what's the matter?, file is a base64 representation of avatar

Comment: how to convert to base64?

Comment: should I convert `file` to base64 or `avatar`?

Comment: `file` is null.

Comment: At what point did you check the value of `file`? If you write it to the console inside the `onload` function, it should show you the complete data URL.

Answer (score 1):

The `atob()` function decodes a string of data which has been encoded using base-64 encoding. Conversely, the `btoa()` function creates a base-64 encoded ASCII string from a "string" of binary data.